# My Java server Side not reading more one incoming message from Java Client

Tags: java, client-server

I Create simple programm Server-Client in Java
My server is

```
public class Server {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String inputLine;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        // Create a reader
         bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        // Get the client message
        while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine); //Print
            }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}
Client Side is :

```
public class Client {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hostName = "localhost";
    try (
            Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, 5000);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        String userInput;
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

}

Why my server not reading again? When I debug the programm My programm it's going out of the loop While in Server..I don'w know Why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server seems to be okay. The reason why your server isn't able to read more than one time is this line on **client-side**:

```
System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
```

The client expects an answer from the server, but your server does not send anything back. So remove the above line or make the server send a response.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is not sending any new line to the server. Its stuck trying to read response from the server.

- System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine()); *

You have two options to fix this

1 - Send a response in Server back to the client
2 - Remove the in.readLine()

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Ok now My server Is run Perfectly ..Now I have one client In android and when i send one message the Server Programm show me the message and then the Server terminated>.. Here is the programm in android Programm When i push the Button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                messsage = textField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
                textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();


            }
        });
    }
        private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {

                    client = new Socket("192.168.2.3", 5000); // connect to the server
                    printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                    printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream

                    printwriter.flush();
                    printwriter.close();
                  //  client.close(); // closing the connection

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }
```